# How to add vb.net condition inside MySql query

Tags: c#, mysql, vb.net, datagridview

I am using `Datagridview` and getting the cell value. What I need to do is, when there an `pieces` string value inside the Cells of `DatagridView` then I change it on my query as 'None'. I am using `case` query already, and I think this is not the  correct answer to solve my problem. Can you help me guys? 
By the way this is my code, what I've done already.

```
For k As Integer = 0 To dtgOrder.RowCount - 1
                objconn.Open()
                cmbQuery = "SELECT product_quantity.Quantity As 'quant_test' from product_quantity 
                            INNER join product_table on product_quantity.Product_ID = product_table.Product_ID 
                           where product_size.Size_Name
                           =  '" & If dtgOrder.Rows(k).Cells(3).Value = "pieces" Then 
                                   dtgOrder.Rows(k).Cells(3).Value = "None" 
                                   End If & "'"
                objcmd = New MySqlCommand(cmbQuery, objconn)
                objdr = objcmd.ExecuteReader
                While objdr.Read
                    quantitytesting = objdr.GetInt32("quant_test")
                End While
                objconn.Close()
Next
```

And this is my query already on `Case` using mysql and I also apply it already on my above query.

```
    SELECT product_quantity.Quantity As 'quant_test' from product_quantity 
    INNER join product_table on product_quantity.Product_ID = product_table.Product_ID 
     where product_size.Size_Name
 =  (Case when '"& dtgOrder.Rows(k).Cells(3).Value = "pieces" &"' Then 'None' Else '"& dtgOrder.Rows(k).Cells(3).Value &"')"
```

Comment: In Sql Server, I'd just pass the value in from VB and code the SQL like this: `WHERE product_size.Size_Name = coalesce(nullif( @Cell3Value , 'pieces'), 'None')` Not sure if MySql has a `NULLIF()` function. ... ... hmm, quick google search says it does.

Answer (score 0):

The first, and by far most important, thing to understand is that you should **NEVER** use string concatenation to put a value into an SQL query. The code you have so far is just begging to get your DB hacked.

That out of the way, there are two possible solutions here.

**In VB:**

```vb
Const SQL As String = _
    "SELECT product_quantity.Quantity As 'quant_test' " & 
    " FROM product_quantity " &
    " INNER join product_table on product_quantity.Product_ID = product_table.Product_ID " &
    " WHERE product_size.Size_Name = @SizeName"
                       =  '
Using cn  As New MySlConnection("connection string here"), 
      cmd As New MySqlCommand(SQL, cn)

    Dim p As MySqlParameter = cmd.Parameters.Add("@SizeName", MySqlDbType.VarString)
    cn.Open()

    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dtgOrder.Rows
        p.Value = If(row.Cells(3).Value = "pieces", "None", row.Cells(3).Value)
        Using objdr As MySqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
            While objdr.Read
                quantitytesting = objdr.GetInt32("quant_test")
            End While
        End Using
    Next
End Using
```

There are number of important improvements to this code over the original, so study the pattern for future use. But while I'm here, I'll also add that it's very strange to see a query like this in a loop with a DataGridView. The rows in that DataGridView almost certainly came from the database, meaning you should be able to build a single query to produce your results, without needing any loop at all. Getting this into a single query will be **much, much better** than making your DB run this multiple times.

**In the SQL:**

```vb
Const SQL As String = _
    "SELECT product_quantity.Quantity As 'quant_test' " & 
    " FROM product_quantity " &
    " INNER join product_table on product_quantity.Product_ID = product_table.Product_ID " &
    " WHERE product_size.Size_Name = COALESCE(NULLIF(@SizeName, 'pieces'),'None')"
                       =  '
Using cn  As New MySlConnection("connection string here"), 
      cmd As New MySqlCommand(SQL, cn)

    Dim p As MySqlParameter = cmd.Parameters.Add("@SizeName", MySqlDbType.VarString)
    cn.Open()

    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dtgOrder.Rows
        p.Value = row.Cells(3).Value
        Using objdr As MySqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
            While objdr.Read
                quantitytesting = objdr.GetInt32("quant_test")
            End While
        End Using
    Next
End Using
```

Of the two I options I prefer the first... make the client app do this particular work rather than the database. I post this because if you do try to get this down to a single SQL statement, you may need this logic to make it work.

Comment: Ahmm. ok Sir. but what if on inserting? There an error:                                                                      With objcmd
                                    .Connection = cn
                                .CommandText = "Insert Into order_table(Order_ID,Product_ID,Order_Quantity,Size_ID,Order_Date)  values (NULL,(Select Product_ID from product_table where Product_Name = " &
" @Prod,@Quant,(Select Size_ID from product_size  where Size_Name =  @SizeNam),CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);  "


                                    .ExecuteNonQuery()
                                End With

Comment: Same things:  use **parameterized queries**, not string concatenation, to build your sql. And you can replace the values clause of an INSERT statement with an SELECT statement: `INSERT INTO Order_Table (Product_ID, Order_Quantity, Size_ID, Order_date) SELECT Product_ID, @Quant, Size_ID, current_timestamp FROM Product_Table p INNER JOIN Product_Size ON ... WHERE ...`